# Poor performance when modifying appSettings

Tags: c#, performance, configuration, app-config, appsettings

I have an application in which I create a TreeView from the values of a database and display it with checkboxes.
Now I want to write the selected values into the appSettings. I tried to do this with this code.
But the performance is so bad, that this probably can't be the right way.
How can I solve it better?

```
public static void SearchAndSaveSelectedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        DeleteSetting(n.Name);

        if (n.Checked)
        {
            UpdateSetting(n.Name, n.Name + "@" + n.FullPath);
        }
        SearchAndSaveSelectedNodes(n.Nodes);
    }
}

public static void DeleteSetting(string key)
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}

public static void UpdateSetting(string key, string value)
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you serialize it to another file?

Comment: Two things. First: if updating an entry, you always delete twice (DeleteSettings, then UpdateSettings, that also deletes). Second: you open and write that file for every node seperately, why not updating it in one step? How many nodes are relevant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you open/save/refresh.. etc. the config many times, redundantly.

I've quickly "inlined" the required calls so they're only executed when needed and added a 2nd method to make the recursive calls without opening/saving repeatedly. (UNTESTED)

Check if that works for you.

```
public static void SearchAndSaveSelectedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    // open config (only once)
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // make edits (recursive)
    SearchAndSaveSelectedNodesRecursive(nodes, config);

    // save (only once)
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    // (afaik there is no need to refresh the section)
}

private static void SearchAndSaveSelectedNodesRecursive(TreeNodeCollection nodes, Configuration config)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(n.Name);
        if (n.Checked)
        {
            // no need to delete again here (it's already deleted)
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(n.Name, n.Name + "@" + n.FullPath);
        }
        SearchAndSaveSelectedNodesRecursive(n.Nodes, config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As with any file handling, you need to open the file *once*, make all your changes and then save the file *once*. The way you structured it, the file is opened for each entry, the entry is written and then the file is saved.

Just imagine you would have to type this into an editor and you would open and close the editor after each line instead of opening once, typing it all and then saving it once.